# using $split for twice in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

Let say in simple my document in mongodb is like this:

```
{'status' = {'tat': 'a, b <b>, c, d <d>' } }
```

I want to separate them and print it like

```
{bbced_name  : 'a'},
{bbced_name : 'b'},
{bbced_name : 'c'}, 
{bbced_name : 'd'},
```

Therefore I try to split the data for twice. The first one is that to split the text with separator comma, then I split again with the separator < :

```
#the first split
project = { "$project" : { "bcced_name" : {
    "$split" : 
        ["$status.tat", ", "]
    }
}

} 
unwind = {"$unwind" : "$bcced_name"}
#the second split
project2= {"$project" : { "bbced_name2" : { 
    "$split" : 
        ["$cced_name", "<"]
    }
}
}
unwind2 = {"unwind" : "$bbced2"}

cur = collection.aggregate([project, unwind, project2, unwind2])
```

could I use split for twice in one pipeline? The first split is working well, but the second isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can below aggregation in `3.4`.

[`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) to create a array of string values followed by [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to output a [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/) value from start of the string to delimiter `<`.

Each substring end value is calculated by iterating the string using [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to output the location of the `<` string.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate(
[{"$project":
   {"bcced_name":
    {"$map":{
      "input":{"$split":["$status.tat",", "]},
      "as":"tat",
      "in":{
        "$cond":[
          {"$eq":[{"$strLenCP":"$$tat"},1]},
          "$$tat",
          {
          "$substrCP":[
            "$$tat",
            0,
            {
              "$arrayElemAt":[
                {"$filter":{
                  "input":{"$range":[0,{"$strLenCP":"$$tat"},1]},
                  "as":"r",
                  "cond":{"$eq":[{"$substrCP":["$$tat","$$r",2]}," <"]}}
                },
              0]
            }
           ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
},
{"$unwind": "$bcced_name"}
])
```

Update: (Use [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/))

```
db.collection_name.aggregate(
[{"$project":
   {"bcced_name":
     {"$map":{
        "input":{"$split":["$status.tat",", "]},
        "as":"tat",
        "in":{
          "$cond":[
            {"$eq":[{"$strLenCP":"$$tat"},1]},
              "$$tat",
            {
            "$substrCP":[
              "$$tat",
               0,
               { "$indexOfCP": [ "$$tat", " <" ] }
             ]
            }
          ]
         }
       }
      }
     }
   },
  {"$unwind": "$bcced_name"}
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram. this is the second time you help me. I have another question. Is there a way to use $map aggregate in order to change date string to become type within pipeline?

I wouldn't  change the date format in datebase

Comment: You are welcome. You can try [dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator available in 3.6. It is not possible to convert date string to type in old version.

Comment: is it possible to use condition $cond : [{$$tat, {$regex : "<" }, then : ignore it. Because the length of my data is unpredictable, so I counldn't use $strLenCP.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Can you use `$indexOfCP` instead ? I've updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Veeram could you please have a look at my code below. The idea is split the sting with separator comma, then check if there is string <. If yes, split it again. But I stack with code "in" {"$arrayElemAt" : ["$$tat2", 0]} because $$tat2 is not an array but string

Comment: Your code above is correct, however I can't use it because the string length is unpredicted

Answer (score 0):

```
{"$project":{
  "bcced_name":
   {"$map":{
     "input":{"$split":["$status.tat",", "]},
     "as":"tat",
     "in":{
       "$cond":[
         {"$gt":[{"$indexOfCP":["$$tat","<"]},0]},
         {"$arrayElemAt" : [{"$split":["$$tat", "<"]}, 0]},
        "$$tat"
        ]
       }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `$split` returns an array but when you use `$map` it iterates over array elements and pass the array element to `$arrayElemAt` causing the error you mentioned. `$arrayElemAt` takes a array variable.What are trying to achieve using `$arrayElemAt` here ?

Comment: You can pass the `$split` expression directly into `$arrayElemAt` instead of `$map`. Something like `{"$arrayElemAt" : [{"$split":["$$tat", "<"]}, 0]}`.Is that what you are after ? I've updated answer.

Comment: Lovely, but there is error @Veeram
$substrCP: length must be a nonnegative integer

Comment: There is `$substrCP` in this answer. Are you using the correct answer ?

Comment: Yes, I use the updated code
And also, this code {"$eq":[{"$strLenCP":"$$tat"},1]}, 
both the first and the second length of string are not predicted

Comment: Oh yah, I am so sory. I was copying your updated code. That's whay there is an error. Thank you very much. Have a nice day/night :)